# Click to hide in the Hero content is not aligned correctly for the non joined communities

Tags: feature-request, design, anonymous-visitors

The "Click to hide" icon in the hero content (welcoming message) for the non joined communities are not aligned correctly for most of the private beta and some other communities.

A few examples are:

> [image: Click to hide]

Can the icon be aligned to the right hand side with correct padding?

Comment: Can you elaborate on *"hero content"*?

Comment: This is still broken :( I didn't even realise there was still a close button available – it's literally just a tiny line in the corner, which hardly looks like a close button even when it's in the right place.